# Best practise in JavaScript to handle cases where one control affects other controls and vice versa

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, frontend

I have a situation where on the same HTML page theye are three separated user controls, each has a list box in it for data selection. The case is that if a user selects a value in the first user control list box, it affects the data source of the other two user controls. And vice versa.
And if the user selects a data in the other user controls , it must update the first user control that a change in data happened and it needs to do something.

I was thinking of using the Observer design pattern to implement this, and after a short Googling came up with various results , such as:

https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13914/Observer-Design-Pattern-Using-JavaScript

BUT, is this really the best practice ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the popular MVVM frameworks, such as Knockout, Angular, etc.? These will make you're life a lot easier.

Comment: I am familiar with AngularJS and used it just lately, my question is about the design pattern itself, is Observer the best practice ? (BTW, I cannot use angular here due to various obligations )

Comment: Yes it is. `select` events everywhere in your app. Though you may want to use a mediator instead of letting the three controls observe each other directly.